# Add Multiple Meta Sections Dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

What I would like to do, is dynamically add a meta box or section of a meta box. The first part is well covered in this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19838/create-more-meta-boxes-as-needed

The above link details dynamically adding song titles, and track numbers to a "My Tracks" meta box. How would I go about adding another layer? For example, being able to add Albums then add song titles and track numbers etc.

Edit: Just to show some code, here is what I have put together.

```
// Add Menu Meta Boxes
function add_menu_item_box()
{
    add_meta_box( 'menu-name',
            __( 'Menus'), 'menu_meta_box_callback', 'menus', 'advanced', 'high');

}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_menu_item_box' );
```

The callback..

```
function menu_meta_box_callback( $post ) {

    wp_nonce_field( 'menu_save', 'menu_meta_box_nonce' ); ?>

    <div id="meta-inner">


    <?php
    $menus = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'menus', true);
    $count = 0;
    var_dump($menus);
    if (is_array($menus)) {
        foreach ($menus as $menu => $item) {  ?>
            <div style="border: 2px solid">
                <label for="menus['+count+'][menu-name]">Section Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="menu-section" name="menus[<?php echo $count ?>][menu-name]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item["menu-name"]) ?>" />
                <div>
                    <h3>Items</h3>
                    <label for="menus[<?php echo $count ?>][item-name]">Menu Item</label>
                    <input type="text" id="menu_item" name="menus[<?php echo $count ?>][item-name]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item["item-name"] ) ?>" />
                    <label for="menus[<?php echo $count; ?>][item-price]">Item Price</label>
                    <input type="number" id="menu_price" name="menus[<?php echo $count; ?>][item-price]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item["item-price"] ) ?>" />
                    <label for="menus[<?php echo $count; ?>][item-desc]">Item Description</label>
                    <textarea id="menu_desc" name="menus[<?php echo $count; ?>][item-desc]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item["item-desc"] ) ?>"><?php echo esc_attr( $item["item-desc"] ) ?></textarea>
                    <span class="remove-item">Remove Item</span>
                </div>
                <span id="item-here"></span>
                <span class="add-item"><?php _e('Add Items'); ?></span>
            </div>
            <?php $count++; 
        }
    } ?>
    <script>
        var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var count = <?php echo $count; ?>;
            // Add a new section 
            $(".add-section").click(function() {
                count = count + 1;
                $('#section-here').append('<div class="section"><label for="menus['+count+'][menu-name]">Section Name</label><input type="text" id="menu_name" name="menus['+count+'][menu-name]" value="" /><span class="remove-section">Remove Section</span><div><label for="menus['+count+'][item-name]">Menu Item</label><input type="text" id="menu_item" name="menus['+count+'][item-name]" value="" /><label for="menus['+count+'][item-price]">Item Price</label><input type="number" id="menu_price" name="menus['+count+'][item-price]" value="" /><label for="menus['+count+'][item-desc]">Item Description</label><textarea id="menu_desc" name="menus['+count+'][item-desc]" value=""></textarea><span class="remove-item">Remove Item</span></div><span id="item-here"></span><span class="add-item"><?php _e('Add Items'); ?></span><span class="remove-section">Remove Section</span></div>');
                $("#menu_item:last-of-type").focus();
                return false;
            });
            // Add items to current section
            $(".add-item").click(function() {
                count = count + 1;
                $('#item-here').append('<div><label for="menus['+count+'][item-name]">Menu Item</label><input type="text" id="menu_item" name="menus['+count+'][item-name]" value="" /><label for="menus['+count+'][item-price]">Item Price</label><input type="number" id="menu_price" name="menus['+count+'][item-price]" value="" /><label for="menus['+count+'][item-desc]">Item Description</label><textarea id="menu_desc" name="menus['+count+'][item-desc]" value=""></textarea><span class="remove-item">Remove Item</span>');
                $("#menu_item:last-of-type").focus();
                return false;
            });
             $(".remove-item").live('click', function() {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
            $(".remove-section").live('click', function() {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
    </div>
    <span id="section-here"></span>
    <span class="add-section"><?php _e('Add Section'); ?></span>
```

Save function

```
<?php }

function menu_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;
        if ( !isset( $_POST['menu_meta_box_nonce'] ) )
        return;

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['menu_meta_box_nonce'], 'menu_save' ) )
        return;
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'menus' );
    // sort through menus array and save
    $menus = $_POST["menus"];
    foreach ($menus as $menu) {
        update_post_meta($post_id,'menus',$menus);  
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'menu_save_postdata' );

?>
```

The above code will add sections, and fields and delete them. The problem is, when I save items, they are appended to the 1st section instead of the section they were added to. Also, add items functionality does not work on a dynamically created section that has not been saved

Comment: Do you mean like adding an element to the screen? Not adding <meta> tags?

Comment: Yeah, adding more elements using `add_meta_boxes`

Comment: Not sure it will help but the 2nd parameter for update_post_meta is the key used. You save everything with menus and therefore it will end up in the same list.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but saving the value doesn't save all the fields (item name, price, description). Perhaps I need to use the section name as the key instead of the count? But how would I deal with adding multiple items?